# Perform a SQL Update query in Talend, i.e. Updata a Table based on another table using Talend components

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, talend

I have 2 table A and B, say

[image: Tables]

Now as in SQL Server to update A based on B - we will write

```
update A
set A.marks= B.marks
from A 
INNER join B
on A.[name] = B.[name] and A.[id]=B.[id]
```

I want to automate this process using Talend components, although I am able to do this using **tMap** component but it is returning only the matched rows i.e. ignoring the fourth row in our output shown above. And I want entire output, i.e. A simple update as we do in Talend.

Have also tried to do **tMSSqlrow** but its not working out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide your ETL process (as a picture for example) or more information in what exactly you have done. This makes it easier for others to help (see also [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: if the 2 table in the same database then just go with writing SQL and executing that from Talend. It's very ineffective to pull the data out.

tMSSqlRow should work fine. Could you try and remove the [] brackets, and see if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar approach to illustrate.
You must change the inputs to tMSSqlInput components and the output  to tMSSqlOutput with the "action on data" -> UPDATE.

[image: Job Design]

[image: tMap]

[image]